# Will tracker-store eventually stop stealing cpu?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, tracker

I've understood that tracker-store is a part of Gnome and that it has something to do with indexing a lot of stuff. Many people have complained about it and I have found lots of instructions for how to disable it. Like these:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9822/how-do-i-disable-tracker-in-gnome/

https://www.soimort.org/notes/171103/

But one question I have not found an answer to yet is if it eventually will go down to reasonable levels. It seems reasonable that it has to do a lot of work on a newly installed system.

So do I have to disable it to stop it from stealing cpu, or will it eventually stop on its own? So far it has been running for two days.

Another question is if there is a way to see how far it has come in its indexing progress.

EDIT:

I think (but I'm not sure) I found a command to see the progress, but that did certainly not make me happy. The command is `tracker status` and it shows this after two days:

```
$ sudo tracker status
Currently indexed: 0 files, 0 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 43.2 GB (88.16%)
All data miners are idle, indexing complete
```

Comment: it is more then 6 days on my system :-((( I posted a similliar question... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482390/usr-lib-tracker-tracker-store-causes-very-heavy-cpu-load-on-debian-buster If I run `tracker status` I get: `Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying`

Comment: hey man seems I found a nasty fix, check  my self-answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483961/240990 on my post. Works for the moment, haven't tested a reboot though